# When stitching images using warpPerspective right hand side image is skewed

Tags: python, opencv, computer-vision, homography, image-stitching

I'm using following code to stitch frames of two videos and it works reasonably well. But in stitched result right hand side image looks bit skewed. I'm unable to think of a reason for this

```
    def detectAndDescribe(self, image):
        gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

        # AKAZE
        descriptor = cv2.AKAZE_create()
        (kps, features) = descriptor.detectAndCompute(image, None)

        kps_np = np.float32([kp.pt for kp in kps])

        # return a tuple of keypoints and features
        return (kps_np, features, kps)



    def matchKeypoints(self, kpsA, kpsB, featuresA, featuresB, ratio, reprojThresh):
        matcher = cv2.BFMatcher(cv2.NORM_HAMMING)
        rawMatches = matcher.knnMatch(featuresA, featuresB, 2)
        matches = []

        for m in rawMatches:
            if len(m) == 2 and m[0].distance < m[1].distance * ratio:
                matches.append((m[0].trainIdx, m[0].queryIdx))

        if len(matches) > 4:
            ptsA = np.float32([kpsA[i] for (_, i) in matches])
            ptsB = np.float32([kpsB[i] for (i, _) in matches])

            (H, status) = cv2.findHomography(ptsA, ptsB, cv2.RANSAC,
                reprojThresh)

            return (matches, H, status, matchesDraw)

        return None


    #Stitching code

    (imageB, imageA) = images
    (kps_np_A, featuresA, kpsA) = self.detectAndDescribe(imageA)
    (kps_np_B, featuresB, kpsB) = self.detectAndDescribe(imageB)


    M = self.matchKeypoints(kps_np_A, kps_np_B, featuresA, featuresB, ratio, reprojThresh)

    if M is None:
        return None

    self.cachedH = M[1]

    result = cv2.warpPerspective(imageA, self.cachedH, (imageA.shape[1] + imageB.shape[1], imageA.shape[0]))
    result[0:imageB.shape[0], 0:imageB.shape[1]] = imageB
    return result
```

What cause this weird transformation and what is the way to fix this. I'm here using AKAZE but even with SIFT issue exists

[image]

Comment: I dont understand what you are meaning. Looks like a general perspective transformation to me. You could try rigidTransformation instead, if you want less degrees of freedom. The reason for this behaviour is perspective and the fact that even perspective transfirnations can only describe planar scenes or purely rotational pinhole camera movement perfectly.

Comment: @Micka I want stitched output to fill out the entire width and height so output looks fine. But have no idea how to get it. What is your suggestion. How can I change my existing code to do it. I didn't understand what you meant exactly. Could you please elaborate more

Comment: please take some research about all the algorithms you use. To stretch/distort parts of the image you could use some spline image transformations, but I dont know about an open source implrmentation.